# What is the meaning of the expression « Cela n’a pas manqué d’arriver. » and « Ça n’a pas manqué. »

Tags: expressions, constructions

I would like to know if I have the correct meanings of (a) and (b).

**(a)** **« Cela n’a pas manqué d’arriver. »**

**(b)** **« Ça n’a pas manqué. »**.

[image]

[*Please click here to go to Académie Française from where this screenshot was taken*](https://www.dictionnaire-academie.fr/article/A9M0575)

I think the meaning of **(a)** **in English** is “It’s definitely going to happen.”

I think the meaning of **(b)** **in English** is “It’s definitely going to happen.” also.

**Questions**

(1) The English meanings I have given may not be the best English translations but that’s okay as **all I really need to know is if I have the **BASIC** meaning of (a) and (b) correct**. Could you please confirm if I’m right please.

(2) My last question is, is it possible to swap the verb **arriver** in « Cela n’a pas manqué d’**arriver**. » for any other verb? That is, could I say **« Cela n’a pas de faire. »** which would mean “It will definitely be made.” **So all I need for this question is a yes or no answer**.

Thank you for your help guys!

Comment: You gave the same meaning to a and b. Is that what you intended?

Answer (score 1):

The meaning you give is correct, but not well situated in time. See this translation of [Larousse](https://www.larousse.fr/dictionnaires/francais-anglais/manquer/49143)

> - ça ne manquera pas = ***it's sure*** OU ***bound to happen*** (in the future)
> - j'ai dit qu'elle reviendrait et ça n'a pas manqué! = I said she'd come back and ***sure enough(she did)***! (in the past)

So both **a** and **b** actually mean: *it definitely **did** happen!* (not "going to happen").

As for your second question, yes, you can change the verb and say

> Cela n’a pas manqué ***de faire*** (des vagues, par exemple).

This sentence would mean ***it definitely did make waves***. "ça ne manquera pas de + verbe" is quite common (I found many hits on [Google](https://www.google.com/search?safe=strict&sxsrf=ALeKk00l4OlZjcMNsTfHMSWHyVA4tje65g%3A1612361830901&ei=ZrAaYN_ANof0gQbF9riACA&q=%22%C3%A7a%20ne%20manquera%20pas%20de%22&oq=%22%C3%A7a%20ne%20manquera%20pas%20de%22&gs_lcp=CgZwc3ktYWIQAzIICAAQFhAKEB4yBggAEBYQHjIGCAAQFhAeMgYIABAWEB4yBggAEBYQHjIGCAAQFhAeMgYIABAWEB46CQgAELADEAoQHjoECCMQJzoGCAAQChAeUNG3BljgwgZgjM8GaAFwAHgAgAHtAogB7ASSAQUzLjMtMZgBAKABAaoBB2d3cy13aXrIAQHAAQE&sclient=psy-ab&ved=0ahUKEwjfi7jx883uAhUHesAKHUU7DoAQ4dUDCA0&uact=5)). Note, however, that if you change the verb in "ça ne manquera pas d'***arriver***", it will cease to be an idiomatic phrase.

If you mean to say "It will definitely be made" the "correct" way would be:

> Cela ne manquera pas d'être fait.

But this sentence doesn't sound native at all. I found only one poor hit on [Google](https://www.google.com/search?safe=strict&sxsrf=ALeKk01p_G3kFDqM7FdTPYoR3BJVIA-GmA%3A1612292792684&ei=uKIZYLWgKdOP8gLX3qDYCg&q=%22%C3%87a%20ne%20manquera%20pas%20d%27%C3%AAtre%20fait%22&oq=%22%C3%87a%20ne%20manquera%20pas%20d%27%C3%AAtre%20fait%22&gs_lcp=CgZwc3ktYWIQAzoHCAAQRxCwA1CF5RZY5fcWYIyDF2gDcAJ4AIABWogBuQKSAQE0mAEAoAECoAEBqgEHZ3dzLXdpesgBCMABAQ&sclient=psy-ab&ved=0ahUKEwi13LnZ8svuAhXTh1wKHVcvCKsQ4dUDCA0&uact=5). There are much better ways of saying that in French.

Comment: Thank you so much @fev for answering my questions !!!  My last question is does the sentence *« Cela ne **manquera** pas de faire qqch. »* = “It’s definitely making/doing sth.” ?

Comment: No, it means "It will definitely do/make something". "manquera" is in the future.

Comment: On ne peut pas remplacer « arriver » par « faire » dans « Ça n'a pas manqué d'arriver. ».

Comment: What I meant is that such a stricture does exist. But you are right, it ceases to be an idiomatic phrase. Will edit.

Comment: @fev I don't understand what you mean by stricture (restriction) here; however, what I am saying is that the construction "Ça n'a pas manqué de faire.", without a complement for "faire", is not used at all. The Google page you added does not contain a single instance of that (in all cases there is a complement). Therefore you should make precise that this complement is needed.

Comment: it's a typo. I meant structure.

Comment: When a comment from your post is intended to someone in particular you have to use the arobase followed by the name. I am not being been notified for your comments; also, I noticed your ngrams are not readable; there is at least one method for giving them a size permitting to read them without any transformation: choose a zoom above 100 % before making a capture. There is possibly a better method but I do not any other way than this one.

Comment: @LPH: Ok, points taken. Thank you. (P.S. If you click on an ngram picture in a post, doesn't this enlarge the picture enough?)

Comment: I didn't know about this means; the ngram is certainly sufficiently enlarged and it's  easy enough to do. However, I don't know whether too many people know about it.